# can I set predefined User input values while debugging in visual studio

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

```
for (int r = 0; r < rooms; r++)
    {
        for ( int a = 0; a < apartments; a++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < floors; f++)
            {

                cin >> Area[f][a][r];
            }

        }
    }
```

this is a  part of my project. In this function i need to take input from the user in a 3-dimensional array. The dimensions could be any thing less than 11. for example  if the size of array is 5 * 5 * 5 than total entries are 125. while debugging, i cannot enter all those entries each time i test it . is there any way in visual studio through which i can set all those values once and use that each time i debug it  .

Comment: Conditionally read from a file. Or redirect stdin to a file in the "run command", somewhere in the settings.

Comment: You can have every value in your clipboard too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to VC++ Project->Properties->Debugging, and input the arguments in the Command line arguments.

Comment: you will also have to read them in, which might require some additional work (global variable?), depending on where in the projects the input is needed

Comment: Thanks for slawekwin's additional notes. @Hassaan Elahi, what about this issue? Any update?